# Android - Secondary Thread to draw on GoogleMap in main UI Thread

Tags: java, android, multithreading

So my main UI Thread is basically a SupportMapFragment. I have a utility class that pulls some data out of local database and then draws some markers on the map.

The method that draws markers on the map which is in the main UI thread is called populate(); The problem here is however if I wrap this inside a second Thread I get Not on the main thread error.

My code:

```
  /**
   * Reacts to camera change events triggered
   * by user. Mainly detecting zoom event.
   */
  public void onCameraChange(CameraPosition pos)
  {
    // Check if zoom differs from our own
    if(pos.zoom != zoom || x != pos.target.latitude || y != pos.target.longitude)
    {
      // Record new zoom
      zoom = pos.zoom;

      // Re refrence location
      x = pos.target.latitude;
      y = pos.target.longitude;


      Thread render = new Thread()
      {
        public void run()
        {
          // Open database for reading
          Database db = new Database(context);

          // Fetch all atms in scope
          ArrayList<Atm> atms;

          // Fetch all atms within visible scope
          atms = db.getAtms(getTopLeft(), getTopRight(), getBottomLeft());
          db.close();

          // Clear map
          map.clear();

          // Populate map with atms
          populate(atms);          // ERROR HERE

          // Exit thread
          return;
        }
      };

      render.start();


      // Confirm change
      setChanged();
      // Notify observers
      notifyObservers(zoom);
    }

  }
```

Even tho following code is executed very fast. The problem is that the main UI still chockes a bit for instance I will open my map and press zoom in it will freeze for like 0.01 seconds until this code is executed and then it will zoom in.

Comment: Any reason you're not using AsyncTask?

Comment: @MattLogan I havent tried it but considering I would be having second thread drawing something on the map of a first thread wouldnt the problem persist ?

Comment: @MattLogan Also AsyncTask requires to extend AsyncTask class which I can't since I'm already Extending observer class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So my main UI Thread is basically a SupportMapFragment

`SupportMapFragment` is a Java object. It is not a thread.

> The problem here is however if I wrap this inside a second Thread I get Not on the main thread error.

Use an `AsyncTask`. Put your database I/O in `doInBackground()` and populate your markers in `onPostExecute()`.

> I would be having second thread drawing something on the map of a first thread wouldnt the problem persist ?

No, because `onPostExecute()` is called on the main application thread.

> Also AsyncTask requires to extend AsyncTask class which I can't since I'm already Extending observer class

[`Observer` is an interface](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Observer.html), not a class.

Comment: I'm not really sure how to implement AsyncTask since doInBackground() should not be manually called and I want to execute that code multiple times. I think Thread/Runnable should be it but this wont allow me to draw on the map.

Comment: @kellax: "I'm not really sure how to implement AsyncTask since doInBackground() should not be manually called and I want to execute that code multiple times" -- I do not know the specifics behind "execute that code multiple times", but the typical approach is to simply execute an `AsyncTask` each time. "I think Thread/Runnable should be it" -- you are welcome to roll your own thread and use methods like `runOnUiThread()` on `Activity` to have certain work be done on the main application thread. Using `AsyncTask` would be simpler.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/9437837b68f79fdd085e Look at my code the class is instantiated once in my main activity. Now on line 129 i have onCameraChange() method inside it on line 142 and up to line 168 I have a task that is somewhat expansive the for loop will do 100 cycles but the contains method it self is a "for loop". My question now is how can I move this in to a second thread with AsyncTask ?

Comment: @kellax: Well, to be honest, I'd delete all of that and use an existing clustering solution, such as https://code.google.com/p/android-maps-extensions/. Beyond that, the code should run very quickly as it is, as you are not doing any I/O, and so it should not be "somewhat expansive". Use Traceview to determine what precisely is your performance issue.